# Determine how many roots of special n-degree polynomial are positive integers

Tags: polynomials, roots

I have a special polynomial of the form $x^n + bx + c = 0$
$c = b - 1$
How can I determine how many of the possible values of $x$ are positive integers?
All values of $n$ will be positive integers.

Comment: Oops, I made a mistake. I updated it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine the *rational root* test with *Descartes' rule of signs* to obtain an upper bound for the number of positive (real) roots.

If $n$ is fixed, *Sturm's algorithm* will give you the exact number of (real) positive roots $\le c$.

Comment: The rational root test limits the *integer* roots to $\pm$ divisors of $c$.

Comment: @vonbrand: That's why I wrote *combine*. There may be more (positive) divisors than the number of positive real roots.